# List all LocalSymbols

Tags: symbols, localsymbol

I was working with a LocalSymbol, but after I deleted the cell I came back to the notebook hours later only to forget the name of the variable!

*Is there anyway to see a full list of the named `LocalSymbol` objects that persist in a notebook?*

I tried looking for them with `Names[]` but it doesn't show them.

Comment: They can in general be stored anywhere, but I imagine `FileNames[$LocalSymbolBase]` should get most of them.

Comment: @PatrickStevens This isn't working for me: `In[7]:= LocalSymbol["ab"] = 1
Out[7]= 1 In[8]:= FileNames[$LocalSymbolBase] Out[8]= {}`

Comment: Sorry, my bad - `FileNames` doesn't do what I remembered it doing. `SetDirectory[$LocalSymbolBase]; FileNames[]` would work instead, except that for some unearthly reason `$LocalSymbolBase` has a protocol on the front, so it isn't directly a directory.

Comment: @PatrickStevens That is giving me a `SetDirectory::cdir: Cannot set current directory to file:///Users/Library/Wolfram/Objects/LocalSymbols. >>`

Comment: Precisely my point. You should be able to just trim the `file://` protocol from the front.

Comment: Ah yes, `SetDirectory[StringTake[$LocalSymbolBase, 8 ;;]]; FileNames[]` works

Comment: Would not the command LocalObjects[] have helped?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of no better way than to just look in the local symbols directory. While it's not necessarily true that all local symbols are stored there, it should be true of the defaults (that is, those made as `LocalSymbol["name"]`).

Now, `$LocalSymbolBase` is a string with a protocol prefix (presumably to match it up with `$CloudSymbolBase`, although since that is a `CloudObject` anyway, I'm not sure that the matching-up is very good). Therefore, we can't `SetDirectory` to it immediately. I don't know of a way to get rid of that using a built-in, so I'll just do the following:

```
removePrefix[str_String] := If[StringTake[str, 7] === "file://", StringTake[str, 8;;], str]
```

Then the function you want is:

```
Module[{ret}, 
 SetDirectory[removePrefix@$LocalSymbolBase];
 ret = FileNames[];
 ResetDirectory[];
 ret
]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to view the local symbol directory that you might try.

```
SystemOpen[$LocalSymbolBase]
```

On my system, OS X, this opens a Finder window showing the folder containing the currently existing local symbols.

[image: local_symbols]

Comment: Works on windows 10 as well. Very nice!